# Bullet list and Numbered list in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitextview

Can any body tell me how to add bullet list and numbered list to the selected text in UITextView.

Comment: Here's a class for this! https://codeload.github.com/eyalc/ECListView/zip/master

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check this question: [iphone bullet point list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798930/iphone-bullet-point-list)

You might want to add the unicode char of bulletpoints to your lines (@"\u2022)

```
NSArray * items = ...;
NSMutableString * bulletList = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:items.count*30];
for (NSString * s in items)
{
   [bulletList appendFormat:@"\u2022 %@\n", s];
}
textView.text = bulletList;
```

Comment: how i can change bullets colour?

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram it is text so it should change as you set the textcolor. Depending on how you use these strings of course.

Comment: basically i just want to change the color of bullets.So Please describe how i can?

Comment: You either have to split to bullets from the text or use something like Core Text: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html. It is kinda out of scope for this answer though.