# How to add a bullet point to the start of sentence text in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have one `UITextView` for which text will change according to the selection by user.
Now I want to add a bullet at the start of every sentence. How would this be achieved?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this code described in this thread [Bullet list and Numbered list in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685221/bullet-list-and-numbered-list-in-uitextview),

```
NSArray * items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Mittal",@"Seema",@"Sonal", nil];
NSMutableString * bulletList = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:items.count*30];
for (NSString * s in items)
{
    [bulletList appendFormat:@"\u2022 %@\n", s];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should you must look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685221/bullet-list-and-numbered-list-in-uitextview). It will contain how to display the numbered list in UITextView .
There is also one more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798930/iphone-bullet-point-list) i want to tell you.