# Adding text to UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextView`, I need to add some text in "point form". Something like this:

```
 - > text 1

 - > text 2 

 - > text 3 

 - > text 4
```

My code:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
[self.view addSubView:textView];
```

If I have a string like `text 1 text 2 text 3 text 4`, how can I display it in UITextView with those bullet signs?

Comment: This question is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798930/iphone-bullet-point-list

Comment: If you read the answer you will notice that app store will reject the solution offered. anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use

```
   textview.text = yourString;
   [textview.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:'TheRightTextEndoder'];
```

Afterwords you should place a the right textencoding so that the bullit will be displayed

Comment: what is 'TheRightTextEndoder' ? what does it do ?