# How UILabels display in Number Format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

Is there any way to display `UILabel` like this

- xxxxxx
- xxxxxx
- xxxxxx

or

1. xxxxx
2. xxxxx
3. xxxxx
4. xxxxx

where I will get the data in `UILabel` and the numbers of labels to display dynamically.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798930/iphone-bullet-point-list

Comment: i didn't find labels in that format on search.am trying to add dot in label and adding to front of text label .i want to know whether it is formattedlike that or not and how?

Comment: have you got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Building from comment by iAmbitious:

First case:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three", nil];    
NSMutableString *compoundString = [NSMutableString string];
NSString *bulletString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",0x2022];

for (NSString *str in array) {
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n",bulletString,str];
    [compoundString appendString:tempString];
}

self.textView.text=compoundString;
```

Second case:
Replace the for loop with the following for loop-

```
for (NSString *str in array) {
        NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@\n",[array indexOfObject:str]+1,str];
        [compoundString appendString:tempString];
    }
```

The above used a text view. If you want to use a label set the number of lines property to zero and set the height of label dynamically like below. You can achieve the same:

```
CGSize lineSize = [@"DummyString" sizeWithFont:self.label.font] ;
CGFloat labelHeight = lineSize.height*array.count;
CGRect tempFrame = self.label.frame;
tempFrame.size.height=labelHeight;
self.label.frame=tempFrame;
```